# Gzipped file downloaded from remote with Net::HTTP is not deflated

Tags: ruby

I read that Net::HTTP auto decompress file when the encoding is gzip...
I'm downloading an xml file but the file saved in my folder is still a .gz files.
Is there something to do?

```
   uri = URI(URI.encode(URL))
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path, { "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip", "User-Agent" => "gzip" })

      request.basic_auth AUTHENTICATION[:username], AUTHENTICATION[:password]

      http.request request do |response|
        open "./storage/file/index_full.xml.gz", 'wb' do |io|
          response.read_body do |chunk|
            puts "Writing  #{chunk.length} bits ..."
            io.write chunk
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: What headers is the server sending for this file?

Comment: In the documentation I have

To benefit in your server scripts from gzip, you must use in any HTTP request this additional parameter:

Accept-Encoding: gzip

It will enforce gzipping!

Example:

GET /export/level4/EN/10.xml HTTP/1.1

Host: prf.Icecat.biz

Accept-Encoding: gzip

User-Agent: Firefox/1.0

Comment: Okay, what are the headers that the server is sending?

Comment: => {"server"=>["nginx"],
 "date"=>["Fri, 15 May 2020 08:58:49 GMT"],
 "content-type"=>["application/x-gzip-compressed"],
 "content-length"=>["279621746"],
 "connection"=>["close"],
 "last-modified"=>["Thu, 14 May 2020 04:38:01 GMT"],
 "icecat-repository"=>["shared filesystem"],
 "datanode"=>["bo-data-web-04"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Compression) claims that Net::HTTP automatically decompresses deflated responses. In order to do this, the client must set `Accept-Encoding` header and the server must set `Content-Encoding` header as [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding).

The server you are working with is not setting the `Content-Encoding` header, therefore the client does not decompress the response.

The server does send a gzip-compressed byte stream, but this is not sufficient. (If all clients decompressed everything that was gzip-compressed, you wouldn't be able to download any `.tar.gz` files as is.)

Comment: Yes thank you. I add a decompress routine after the file download